# puppet could not find dependency Package[monit] while applying Gitorious manifest

Tags: rubygems, manifest, puppet, monit, gitorious

I am trying to [install Gitorious](http://getgitorious.com/installer#sec-3) on RHEL 6.3 but I have a similar [issue as Chris](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gitorious/rpQvPgH1hOA):

```
~/gitorious-ce-installer> sudo puppet apply --debug --modulepath=modules manifests/site.pp
[...]
Could not find dependency Package[monit] for File[/etc/monit.conf] at /home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/gitorious/manifests/dependencies.pp:43
```

File `dependencies.pp`:

```
cat -n modules/gitorious/manifests/dependencies.pp | tail -11
    35
    36    file {"/etc/monit.conf":
    37      ensure => present,
    38      owner => "root",
    39      group => "root",
    40      mode => "0600",
    41      source => "puppet:///modules/gitorious/config/monit.conf",
    42      require => Package["monit"],
    43    }
    44
    45  }
```

But I hope Gitorious can be also installed on RHEL 6, not only CentOS 6...
**What could be done to allow `puppet` applying the Gitorious manifests on RHEL?**
(removing the `require` statement in `dependencies.pp`?...)

---

I have installed [`monit`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monit) using `yum`:

```
~/gitorious-ce-installer> sudo yum install monit
Loaded plugins: auto-update-debuginfo, product-id, rhnplugin, 
                security, subscription-manager
Updating certificate-based repositories.
Unable to read consumer identity
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package monit.x86_64 0:5.1.1-4.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

=====================================================
 Package  Arch   Version     Repository         Size
=====================================================
Installing:
 monit    x86_64 5.1.1-4.el6 last-rhel-x86_64   236 k

Transaction Summary
=====================================================
Install       1 Package(s)

Total download size: 236 k
Installed size: 0
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
monit-5.1.1-4.el6.x86_64.rpm    | 236 kB     00:00
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test
Transaction Test Succeeded
Running Transaction
  Installing : monit-5.1.1-4.el6.x86_64          1/1
Installed products updated.
  Verifying  : monit-5.1.1-4.el6.x86_64          1/1

Installed:
  monit.x86_64 0:5.1.1-4.el6

Complete!
```

I have also installed `monit` using `gem`:

```
~/gitorious-ce-installer> sudo gem install monit --no-ri --no-rdoc
Successfully installed monit-0.3.1
1 gem installed
```

This is the full `puppet` output:

```
~/gitorious-ce-installer> sudo puppet apply --debug --modulepath=modules manifests/site.pp
info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/nvidia_controller_count.rb
info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/root_home.rb
info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/ptpd2.rb
info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/cdp_fact.rb
info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/sv_tools.rb
info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/puppet_vardir.rb
info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/facter_dot_d.rb
Could not retrieve arp_eth1: undefined method `get_arp_value' for Facter::Util::IP:Module
Could not retrieve arp_eth4: undefined method `get_arp_value' for Facter::Util::IP:Module
Could not retrieve arp_eth2: undefined method `get_arp_value' for Facter::Util::IP:Module
Could not retrieve arp_eth5: undefined method `get_arp_value' for Facter::Util::IP:Module
Could not retrieve arp_eth0: undefined method `get_arp_value' for Facter::Util::IP:Module
Could not retrieve arp_eth3: undefined method `get_arp_value' for Facter::Util::IP:Module
Could not retrieve arp_lo: undefined method `get_arp_value' for Facter::Util::IP:Module
debug: importing '/home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/manifests/nodes.pp' in environment production
debug: importing '/home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/manifests/os/centos.pp' in environment production
debug: importing '/home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/manifests/tarball.pp' in environment production
debug: importing '/home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/manifests/classes/monit.pp' in environment production
debug: importing '/home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/manifests/classes/mysql.pp' in environment production
debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderRpm: Executing '/bin/rpm --version'
debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderYum: Executing '/bin/rpm --version'
debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderAptrpm: Executing '/bin/rpm -ql rpm'
debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderUrpmi: Executing '/bin/rpm -ql rpm'
debug: importing '/home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/iptables/manifests/init.pp' in environment production
debug: importing '/home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/iptables/manifests/default_firewall.pp' in environment production
debug: Automatically imported iptables from iptables into production
debug: importing '/home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/gitorious/manifests/init.pp' in environment production
debug: importing '/home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/gitorious/manifests/git.pp' in environment production
debug: importing '/home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/gitorious/manifests/dependencies.pp' in environment production
debug: importing '/home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/gitorious/manifests/core.pp' in environment production
debug: importing '/home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/gitorious/manifests/templates.pp' in environment production
debug: importing '/home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/gitorious/manifests/redis.pp' in environment production
debug: importing '/home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/gitorious/manifests/sphinx.pp' in environment production
debug: importing '/home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/gitorious/manifests/logrotate.pp' in environment production
debug: importing '/home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/gitorious/manifests/no_email.pp' in environment production
debug: importing '/home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/gitorious/manifests/git_daemons.pp' in environment production
debug: Automatically imported gitorious from gitorious into production
debug: Failed to load library 'ldap' for feature 'ldap'
debug: Scope(Class[Gitorious::Git]): Retrieving template gitorious/scripts/gitorious_console.erb
debug: template[/home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/gitorious/templates/scripts/gitorious_console.erb]: Bound template variables for /home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/gitorious/templates/scripts/gitorious_console.erb in 0.00 seconds
debug: template[/home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/gitorious/templates/scripts/gitorious_console.erb]: Interpolated template /home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/gitorious/templates/scripts/gitorious_console.erb in 0.00 seconds
debug: No true answers and no default
debug: Scope(Class[Gitorious::Core]): Retrieving template gitorious/gitorious.conf.erb
debug: template[/home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/gitorious/templates/gitorious.conf.erb]: Bound template variables for /home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/gitorious/templates/gitorious.conf.erb in 0.00 seconds
debug: template[/home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/gitorious/templates/gitorious.conf.erb]: Interpolated template /home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/gitorious/templates/gitorious.conf.erb in 0.00 seconds
debug: importing '/home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/gitorious/manifests/database.pp' in environment production
debug: Automatically imported gitorious::database from gitorious/database into production
debug: Scope(Class[Gitorious::Logrotate]): Retrieving template gitorious/gitorious_logrotate.erb
debug: template[/home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/gitorious/templates/gitorious_logrotate.erb]: Bound template variables for /home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/gitorious/templates/gitorious_logrotate.erb in 0.00 seconds
debug: template[/home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/gitorious/templates/gitorious_logrotate.erb]: Interpolated template /home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/gitorious/templates/gitorious_logrotate.erb in 0.00 seconds
debug: importing '/home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/gitorious/manifests/unicorn.pp' in environment production
debug: Automatically imported gitorious::unicorn from gitorious/unicorn into production
debug: Scope(Class[Gitorious::Unicorn]): Retrieving template gitorious/unicorn.rb.erb
debug: template[/home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/gitorious/templates/unicorn.rb.erb]: Bound template variables for /home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/gitorious/templates/unicorn.rb.erb in 0.00 seconds
debug: template[/home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/gitorious/templates/unicorn.rb.erb]: Interpolated template /home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/gitorious/templates/unicorn.rb.erb in 0.00 seconds
debug: Scope(Class[Gitorious::Unicorn]): Retrieving template gitorious/etc/init.d/gitorious-unicorn.erb
debug: template[/home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/gitorious/templates/etc/init.d/gitorious-unicorn.erb]: Bound template variables for /home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/gitorious/templates/etc/init.d/gitorious-unicorn.erb in 0.00 seconds
debug: template[/home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/gitorious/templates/etc/init.d/gitorious-unicorn.erb]: Interpolated template /home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/gitorious/templates/etc/init.d/gitorious-unicorn.erb in 0.00 seconds
debug: Scope(Class[Gitorious::Unicorn]): Retrieving template gitorious/usr/bin/restart_gitorious.erb
debug: template[/home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/gitorious/templates/usr/bin/restart_gitorious.erb]: Bound template variables for /home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/gitorious/templates/usr/bin/restart_gitorious.erb in 0.00 seconds
debug: template[/home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/gitorious/templates/usr/bin/restart_gitorious.erb]: Interpolated template /home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/gitorious/templates/usr/bin/restart_gitorious.erb in 0.00 seconds
debug: importing '/home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/gitorious/manifests/nginx.pp' in environment production
debug: Automatically imported gitorious::nginx from gitorious/nginx into production
debug: Scope(Class[Gitorious::Nginx]): Retrieving template gitorious/etc/nginx/nginx.conf.erb
debug: template[/home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/gitorious/templates/etc/nginx/nginx.conf.erb]: Bound template variables for /home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/gitorious/templates/etc/nginx/nginx.conf.erb in 0.00 seconds
debug: template[/home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/gitorious/templates/etc/nginx/nginx.conf.erb]: Interpolated template /home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/gitorious/templates/etc/nginx/nginx.conf.erb in 0.00 seconds
debug: importing '/home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/gitorious/manifests/utils.pp' in environment production
debug: Automatically imported gitorious::utils from gitorious/utils into production
debug: Scope(Class[Gitorious::Utils]): Retrieving template gitorious/usr/bin/gitorious_status.erb
debug: template[/home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/gitorious/templates/usr/bin/gitorious_status.erb]: Bound template variables for /home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/gitorious/templates/usr/bin/gitorious_status.erb in 0.00 seconds
debug: template[/home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/gitorious/templates/usr/bin/gitorious_status.erb]: Interpolated template /home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/gitorious/templates/usr/bin/gitorious_status.erb in 0.00 seconds
debug: importing '/home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/resque/manifests/init.pp' in environment production
debug: Automatically imported resque from resque into production
debug: Scope(Class[Resque]): Retrieving template resque/etc/init/resque-worker.conf.erb
debug: template[/home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/resque/templates/etc/init/resque-worker.conf.erb]: Bound template variables for /home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/resque/templates/etc/init/resque-worker.conf.erb in 0.00 seconds
debug: template[/home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/resque/templates/etc/init/resque-worker.conf.erb]: Interpolated template /home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/resque/templates/etc/init/resque-worker.conf.erb in 0.00 seconds
debug: No true answers and no default
debug: Scope(Monit::Config[thinking-sphinx]): Retrieving template gitorious/monit.d/thinking-sphinx.monit.erb
debug: template[/home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/gitorious/templates/monit.d/thinking-sphinx.monit.erb]: Bound template variables for /home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/gitorious/templates/monit.d/thinking-sphinx.monit.erb in 0.00 seconds
debug: template[/home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/gitorious/templates/monit.d/thinking-sphinx.monit.erb]: Interpolated template /home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/gitorious/templates/monit.d/thinking-sphinx.monit.erb in 0.00 seconds
debug: Scope(Monit::Config[unicorn]): Retrieving template gitorious/monit.d/unicorn.monit.erb
debug: template[/home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/gitorious/templates/monit.d/unicorn.monit.erb]: Bound template variables for /home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/gitorious/templates/monit.d/unicorn.monit.erb in 0.00 seconds
debug: template[/home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/gitorious/templates/monit.d/unicorn.monit.erb]: Interpolated template /home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/gitorious/templates/monit.d/unicorn.monit.erb in 0.00 seconds
debug: Scope(Gitorious::Config[hostname]): Retrieving template gitorious/gitorious.yml.erb
debug: template[/var/www/gitorious/app/config/gitorious.yml]: Bound template variables for /home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/gitorious/templates/gitorious.yml.erb in 0.00 seconds
debug: template[/var/www/gitorious/app/config/gitorious.yml]: Interpolated template /home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/gitorious/templates/gitorious.yml.erb in 0.00 seconds
debug: Scope(Monit::Config[git-daemons]): Retrieving template gitorious/monit.d/git-daemons.monit.erb
debug: template[/home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/gitorious/templates/monit.d/git-daemons.monit.erb]: Bound template variables for /home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/gitorious/templates/monit.d/git-daemons.monit.erb in 0.00 seconds
debug: template[/home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/gitorious/templates/monit.d/git-daemons.monit.erb]: Interpolated template /home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/gitorious/templates/monit.d/git-daemons.monit.erb in 0.00 seconds
debug: Scope(Gitorious::Nginx::Vhost[hostname]): Retrieving template gitorious/etc/nginx/conf.d/gitorious.conf.erb
debug: template[/home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/gitorious/templates/etc/nginx/conf.d/gitorious.conf.erb]: Bound template variables for /home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/gitorious/templates/etc/nginx/conf.d/gitorious.conf.erb in 0.00 seconds
debug: template[/home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/gitorious/templates/etc/nginx/conf.d/gitorious.conf.erb]: Interpolated template /home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/gitorious/templates/etc/nginx/conf.d/gitorious.conf.erb in 0.00 seconds
debug: Exec[bootstrap_thinking_sphinx]: Adding default for path
debug: Exec[clone_gitorious_source]: Adding default for path
debug: Exec[init_gitorious_submodules]: Adding default for path
debug: Exec[chown_app_root]: Adding default for path
debug: Exec[install_bundler]: Adding default for path
debug: Exec[bundle_install]: Adding default for path
debug: Exec[populate_database]: Adding default for path
debug: Exec[create_database_gitorious_production]: Adding default for path
debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderPorts: file /usr/local/sbin/portversion does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderUp2date: file /usr/sbin/up2date-nox does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderAptitude: file /usr/bin/aptitude does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderFreebsd: file /usr/sbin/pkg_delete does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderApt: file /usr/bin/apt-get does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderSunfreeware: file pkg-get does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderNim: file /usr/sbin/nimclient does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderPkg: file /usr/bin/pkg does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderFink: file /sw/bin/fink does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderRug: file /usr/bin/rug does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderDpkg: file /usr/bin/dpkg does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderSun: file /usr/sbin/pkgrm does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderZypper: file /usr/bin/zypper does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderAix: file /usr/sbin/installp does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderHpux: file /usr/sbin/swlist does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderPortupgrade: file /usr/local/sbin/portversion does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderUrpmi: file urpmq does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderPacman: file /usr/bin/pacman does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderAptrpm: file apt-get does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderPortage: file /usr/bin/emerge does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::Package::ProviderOpenbsd: file pkg_delete does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::Service::ProviderRunit: file /usr/bin/sv does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::Service::ProviderOpenrc: file /sbin/rc-service does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::Service::ProviderDebian: file /usr/sbin/update-rc.d does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::Service::ProviderSystemd: file /bin/systemctl does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::Service::ProviderGentoo: file /sbin/rc-update does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::Service::ProviderLaunchd: file /bin/launchctl does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::Service::ProviderDaemontools: file /usr/bin/svc does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderUser_role_add: file roleadd does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderPw: file pw does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderLdap: feature ldap is missing
debug: Puppet::Type::User::ProviderDirectoryservice: file /usr/bin/dscl does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::Group::ProviderPw: file pw does not exist
debug: Puppet::Type::Group::ProviderLdap: true value when expecting false
debug: Puppet::Type::Group::ProviderDirectoryservice: file /usr/bin/dscl does not exist
debug: Creating default schedules
Could not find dependency Package[monit] for File[/etc/monit.conf] at /home/me/gitorious-ce-installer/modules/gitorious/manifests/dependencies.pp:43
```

Answer (score 2):

It does not matter if the package is installed on the system.

`Package[monit]` refers to a resource, defined in Puppet.

If you would put

```
package { 'monit':
  ensure => installed,
}
```

somewhere in the class, it will work.